# Is it possible to have more than 1 date in 1 column?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables, 1 for `patients` where I have their information and the other is for therapy type and date of therapy.

I need to random therapy dates (10 instances which I already did), I was wondering if it is possible to put all the dates into the same field, because I tried and only get the first date others are displayed like `0000-00-00`.

Example of 2nd database:

```
id  type   date
1   1     2013-09-21
          2013-09-22
          2013-09-23
          2013-09-24
          2013-09-25
          2013-09-26
          2013-09-27
          2013-09-28
          2013-09-29
          2013-09-30 
2   1     ...
and so on...
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking

Comment: Why not use another table with a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship?

Comment: Well it's good to have query, but dare don't implement this query in real projects.

Comment: You cannot add multiple dates to a DATE or DATETIME field however you can add multiple dates along several entries and have an id to identify to which therapy that date belong to.

Comment: can 1 date in mysql support multiple dates (such as this table top, thanks for the edit) or i need a new variable for each one?

Comment: Make 1 table for therapy 1 for holding all the dates with reference to the therapy id and save each date into a new row, then you can easily group the dates by therapy ID and have the desired result.

Comment: just as i thought it is not likely to get something out of it.
thanks ill try to simplify it like that

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can try like this using paranthesis:-

```
INSERT INTO tables(columndates) VALUES ('date1'), ('date2'), ('date3'), ('date4'), ('date5');
```

But it would be good idea to create another table with one-to-many or so relationship. One row should contain one value.